# Reboot USB Port Without Device Reboot

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

My phone has been slowly going insane over the time I've been using it. This time around, the USB port is throwing tantrums. It won't let the phone connect to a PC. I've tried different USB ports on the PC (KDE Neon 5.17 User Edition), changing wires, and trying a different PC (Windows 10 Pro). All of them didn't help. Rebooting the phone helps, restoring normal access, but after unplugging the phone from the PC, it won't connect again unless I reboot the phone. Regardless of access, the phone does get charged if connected to the PC.

1) Any idea what is going on with my phone? No recent software installs or any weird things. Phone isn't that old (Lenovo P2a42, rooted with Magisk 20.2 and running AEX 6.7).

2) Is there any way to "reset" the USB port without rebooting the entire phone (similar to how it would be on a PC)? Everything on the internet only shows either changing the default USB configuration to MTP instead of the default "charge only" or resetting the USB port on Windows.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @beeshyams the PC doesn't even see the device I assume (i.e. not in `adb devices` and maybe not even in `lsusb` – not 100% sure about the latter, might show up there as toaster or whatever). One of my devices does this from time to time – and as the OP describes, only a reboot seems to help. As it works fine after that (for me, not for the OP obviously) and only happes 3..4 times a year, I didn't dig deeper yet. But it got nothing to do with "authorization" (OP didn't even mention ADB – or did you mean something I'm not aware of?)

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, I was talking of adb and rightly pointed out by you that he isn't reached that state yet

Comment: @beeshyams How would I do that?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, it doesn't even show up in ```lsusb```. All the solutions I see online assume it's just an MTP problem, at best they reboot the USB port on the PC.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore. As pointed out by Izzy I misread your situation

Comment: Does this happen with different PCs (especially PCs that don't run Linux)? may be Linux does something that confuses the phone and forces the USB chip into an invalid state. Usually on Android side I would expect a kernel driver to initialize the USB chip and re-initializing could be done by unloading and reloading the driver module. Unfortunately on Android typically there are no kernel modules one could (un)load.

Comment: @Robert I didn't try rebooting the phone and connecting to a Windows PC, but yes, the phone isn't recognized by Windows or Linux after disconnecting from a Linux PC. I do have root access on the phone though, is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: @404 I was talking about connecting the phone to Windows when it is fully working to see if Windows also manages to "destroy" the USB communication.

Comment: @Robert Ah ok. I'll see if it does when I get the chance to do so.

Comment: @404NameNotFound as for details on ADB, please see our [adb tag wiki](/tags/adb/info). But if not even `lsusb` sees your device, ADB won't either. So first things first ;) Follow Robert's hint to see if the cause lies on your Android device or the PC. Depending on which it is, approaches for solutions might differ.

Comment: @Robert Alright I've rebooted my phone and connected to Windows. All is well, connecting and disconnecting as expected. What's surprising is now connecting and disconnecting from Linux is also fine, performing as expected. My phone is slowly going insane, but the question still stands: should the issue return, is there a way I can reboot just the USB port on my phone instead of the entire phone?